# Smoothness of fix point components of finite group action on smooth variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, geometric-invariant-theory

Let $X$ be a *smooth* complex algebraic variety, and $\varphi: \Gamma\curvearrowright X$ an action (by automorphisms) of a *finite* group $\Gamma$ on $X$.

> Can we say that each irreducible component of the fix point set $X^{\Gamma}$ is smooth?

Here $X^{\Gamma}:=\{ x\in X\; | \; g(x):=\varphi_g (x)=x\;\forall g\in\Gamma\; \}$.

Remark: without loss of generality we can assume $X$ affine, since any $\Gamma$-variety can be covered by affine $\Gamma$-invariant open subsets.

Comment: I think this is a consequence of Cartan Lemma. In a neighborhood of a fixed point $p$ the action can be linearized, so locally analytically we may assume $X=\mathbb{C}^n$, $p=0$ and $G \subset \rm{GL}(n, \, \mathbb{C})$. Then in a neighborhood of $0$ the fixed locus is given by a union of linear subspaces and the claim follows.

Comment: If $H$ is a linearly reductive affine group scheme over any field $k$ (e.g., any affine algebraic group with reductive identity component in char. 0, which includes any finite group, as well as any group of multiplicative type in any characteristic) and $Y$ is a separated $k$-scheme of equipped with an $H$-action then the functor $Y^H$ of $H$-fixed points is represented by a closed subscheme of $Y$ (that much doesn't use the linear reductivity) which moreover is smooth whenever $Y$ is smooth.  In particular, irreducible components of $Y^H$ are always pairwise disjoint.

Comment: @user52824: could you please also give a reference?

Comment: @Qfwfq: The case of finite groups with order invertible on the base is in Edixhoven's 1992 paper "Neron models and tame ramification" in Compositio 81 (see 3.1--3.4), and the general case is Prop. A.8.11 in the book "Pseudo-reductive groups" (which gives a proof in a more general setting over rings that generalizes Edixhoven's Prop. 3.4; various aspects simplify when working over a field).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. The reason is that locally around a fixed point, the action linearizes, i.e. is analytically equivalent to a linear action of $\Gamma $ onto a vector space -- so the fixed locus is locally isomorphic to a linear space. This fact, which follows easily from an averaging process, goes back (at least) to H. Cartan, in *Algebraic geometry and topology* (a symposium in honor of S. Lefschetz), pp. 90-102, Princeton University Press, 1957.