# Fixed points under a finite group action on projective variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, algebraic-groups, group-actions, fixed-point-theorems

Let us have an algebraic action by a finite group G on a complex projective variety $X=\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^N X_i$, whose irreducible components $X_i$ are all smooth and of the same dimension $d$, and whose singular cohomology $H^*(X)$ is generated by algebraic cycles (hence supported in even degrees). Note that variety X itself is NOT smooth (unless N=1).
Is there a fixed-points type theorem that would give us that
$$\text{rank}(H^*(X^G))=\text{rank}(H^*(X))?$$

NB I have EDITED the question.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/171525/smoothness-of-fix-point-components-of-finite-group-action-on-smooth-variety

Comment: I am aware that it 1,2,3 holds when the whole variety is smooth. Here I am just saying that its components are smooth, not the variety itself - hence the reason to challenge those statements.

Comment: @Filip92: 1. does not hold even for *smooth* projective varieties: a translation on an abelian variety has no fixed points.

Comment: @SándorKovács I completely agree. However, I was having in mind examples with non-zero Euler characteristic (as written in my edited question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually a simple answer. Pick X to be two $\mathbb{C}P^1$'s intersecting transversally, and a $\mathbb{Z}/2$ action that swaps two spheres. Then $\text{rk } H^*(X)=3$ whereas $\text{rk } H^*(X^G) = 1.$

Answer (score 8):

### Setup

Let $G$ be a finite group acting on a smooth projective
variety $X$, and let
$$
\rho: G \times X \to X
$$
be the action morphism. For any $g \in G$ let $\rho_g$ denote the composition 
$$
X \simeq \{g\} \times X \subset G \times X \xrightarrow{\rho} X
$$

### The fixed point locus $X^G \subset X$ is a closed subscheme

(possibly empty):

**Edit incorporating Peter McNamara's comment:** $X^G$ is always closed when $G$ is an affine algebraic group (link in comments).

When $G$ is finite there's an elementary argument: note that for any $g \in G$, the $g$-fixed points $X^g$ fit
into the cartesian diagram
$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
X^g @>>> X \\
@VVV @V \mathrm{id} \times \rho_g VV \\
X @> \Delta >> X \times X
\end{CD}

Since $\Delta$ (and $\mathrm{id} \times \rho_{g}$ for that matter) are
closed immersions and closed immersions are compatible with base
change, $X^{g} \to X$ is a closed immersion. Since $X^{G} = \bigcap_{g
\in G} X^{g}$, $X^{G}$ is also a closed subscheme of $X$.

**Remark**: This heavily relies on the fact that $G$ is a finite (or
at least discrete) group, which is fine since that was the question,
but I'd be interested in whether/when/how-to-show $X^{G}$ is closed in
the case where $G$ is, say, a positive dimensional linearly reductive
affine group scheme acting on $X$.

where $\Delta$ is the diagonal. As Sándor pointed out in a
comment it definitely can happen that $X^{G}$ is empty, e.g. if $X$ is
an abelian variety and $G \subset X$ is a finite subgroup acting by
translations.

### The fixed point locus is smooth

This is more difficult to prove -- an analytic argument due to Cartan
appears in [Algebraic geometry and
topology](https://archive.org/stream/algebraicgeometr032092mbp/algebraicgeometr032092mbp_djvu.txt),
and an alternative approach is [Luna's étale slice
theorem](http://archive.numdam.org/article/MSMF_1973__33__81_0.pdf).

The idea behind both approaches is to get local enough that the local
geometry at a fixed point $x \in X^G$ is modeled by the tangent space
$T_{X,x}$ with it's *linear* $G$--action (if $\rho_{g}: X \to X$ is
the action of $g \in G$ on $X$, then $g$ acts on $T_{X,x}$ via $d
\rho_{g}: T_{X, x} \to T_{X, \rho_{g}(x)} = T_{X, x}$). One then
proves that $T_{X^{G}, x} = T_{X,x}^{G}$, the $G$-invariant
subspace.

I won't attempt to go into further detail.

### The fixed locus can have arbitrary dimension:

Let $\rho: G \times V \to V$ be a linear representation of a finite group $G$. Then
$\mathbb{P}(V)$ is a smooth projective variety with an induced
$G$-action
$$
\bar{\rho}: G \times \mathbb{P}(V) \to \mathbb{P}(V), \, \, \text{
  where  } \bar{\rho}[v] = [\rho(v)]
$$
Observe that for a non-0 vector $v \in V$, $[v] \in \mathbb{P}(V)^{G}$
if and only if for each $g \in G$ there's a scalar $\lambda_{g} \in
\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ so that $\rho_{g}(v) = \lambda_{g} v$. Evidently
this occurs if and only if $v$ lies in the isotypical summand of a
*character* (1-dimensional representation) $L$ of $V$.

This observation together with some representation theory of
finite groups yields examples where $\dim X^{G}$ takes arbitrary
values in $0, \dots, \dim X$.

### Criteria for $X^{G}$ to be non-empty

There are various ``fixed point theorems'' which guarantee the
existence of, well, fixed points. See for instance the [Lefschetz fixed
point
theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lefschetz_fixed-point_theorem)
and the [holomorphic Lefschetz fixed point
theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_Lefschetz_fixed-point_formula). The
later is especially powerful and shows for instance that if
$$
H^{i}(X, \mathscr{O}_{X}) = 0 \,\, \text{  for  } i > 0
$$
(for example, if $X$ is Fano or even just rationally connected) then
$X^{G} \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: Your answer is in great details, thank you for that. However, it is still only for a smooth projective variety, whereas my setup includes (and in general is) rather singular.

Comment: The fixed point locus X^G is always a closed subscheme when G is affine. See https://mathoverflow.net/a/14876 (which ultimately references Prop A.8.10 of Conrad-Gabber-Prasad's book "Pseudo-Reductive Groups").

Comment: @Filip92 at least if $G$ is finite (and maybe more generally, don't know right off the top of my head) you could lift the action of $G$ to the normalization $\coprod_i X_i \to \bigcup_i X_i = X$. Based on your assumptions the normalization is smooth, so anything we know in the smooth projective case would apply to the $G$-action on $\coprod_i X_i$. The trick would be to see what (if anything) fixed points/cohomology calculations on the normalization tell us about those of $X$

Answer (score 7):

The answer to the edited question is **no**. Take  a double covering  $\pi :X\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^2$ branched along a smooth quartic curve $C$ (so $X$ is a Del Pezzo surface), and $G=\langle \sigma \rangle$, where $\sigma $ is the involution such that $\pi \circ\sigma =\pi $. Then $\operatorname{rk} H^*(X)=10$, but $\operatorname{rk} H^*(X^G)=\operatorname{rk} H^*(C)=8$.

Comment: Thanks! Maybe I am missing something but, in my equality, it is rather $\text{rk }(H^*(X))$ instead of $\text{rk }(H^*(X)^G)$ which you've written.

Comment: Oh, sorry. But my example still works, since $\operatorname{rk}H^*(X)=10 $. I have edited my answer.